# Too large of an array leads to a stack overflow error in Visual Studio and a block in Atom

Tags: arrays, c, visual-studio, windows-10, atom-editor

My program is a very simple random number generator with arbitrary parameters. I am using Atom on Windows 10. The code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define LEN 560000

void main() {
    int x[LEN];
    int i;
    
    int m = 1234234;
    int a = 1245;
    int c = 3;
    
    x[0] = 1;
    
    for (i = 1; i < LEN - 2; i++) {
        x[i + 1] = a * (x[i] + c) % m;
    }
    
    printf("%lf\n", ((double)x[LEN-5]) / m);   /* as check */
}
```

I don't receive anything from the terminal but if I change the length of the vector that I want to generate, setting `LEN=500000`, I immediately get the final output (that one with the comment) from the terminal. In addition if I use Visual Studio with the same code I receive an error due to overflow.

I don't understand why if I go from `LEN=500000` to `LEN=560000` the program is not executed.

In my humble opinion I think that there **should be a cutoff of array lengths** in these two compilers i.e. Atom and Visual Studio, since if I make the array a bit longer the program doesn't work.

**EDIT:** the second loop goes from `1` to `LEN-2` but the problem remains.

Comment: Stack overflow?

Comment: Local variables are usually stored on the stack, including arrays (the entire array). On Windows the default stack per process is a single MiB. Your array will take up over 2 MiB assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`, which it is on any modern PC-like system.

Comment: Also remember that array indexes in C are *zero* based, which means an array of `LEN` elements will have indexes from `0` to `LEN - 1` (inclusive). Since you use one-based indexing you will go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes of course so I don't understand the cause of the overflow

Comment: Finally a little nitpicking: Atom is not a compiler, it's a *text editor*. It has functionality to call out to external programs, for example compilers, but it's not in itself a compiler. Neither is Visual Studio, it's an IDE which basically is a very specialized editor with project management and other features, but it's also not a compiler in itself but relies on an external program for the compilation. And it's not the compilers responsibility to protect you agains undefined behavior, it's your responsibility as a programmer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry there was a little mistake in the code, in fact as you have underlined the second`for` loop goes from `1` to `LEN-2` (in fact the problem is the same). Ok but against what it must protect me ?

Comment: Since the C standard doesn't even mention a heap or a stack, there isn't a way for C itself to guard against resource overflow. There is the same problem with recursion:  the stack overflow isn't caught by the language, but by the OS.

Comment: @WeatherVane  unfortunately I don't have linux but using Atom I don't receive any answer from the terminal with the aforementioned value of `LEN`. As I wrote in the body of the question, considering a bit bigger array makes me going from an immediate execution to a blank terminal.

Comment: Then allocate the array dynamically. Visual C still has limits for heap memory, but much larger than stack.

Comment: @WeatherVane I will try with a malloc/calloc .

Comment: In the final `printf`, `x[LEN]` is out of bounds. The last element is `x[LEN-1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allocating more than 2 megabytes of automatic storage in `main()`. It is system dependent whether this exceeds the stack space available to your application and causes a **stack overflow**. You are experiencing undefined behavior, which seems to manifest only when you access elements of `x` that have a high index value, but the mere fact that you define objects with automatic storage that exceeds available stack space is sufficient to invoke undefined behavior.

You can try and modify the initial stack size when running this program, but there is no portable way to specify it: check your system documentation for how to do it.

For a portable solution, you should allocate the array with `malloc()` and make `x` a pointer to `int`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define LEN 560000

int main() {
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(*x) * LEN);
    int i;

    if (x == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failure\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    int m = 1234234;
    int a = 1245;
    int c = 3;
    
    x[0] = 1;
    
    for (i = 1; i < LEN - 2; i++) {
        x[i + 1] = a * (x[i] + c) % m;
    }
    
    printf("%lf\n", ((double)x[LEN]) / m);   /* as check */
    free(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your answer is robust but let me tell you something. I have just tried with this online IDE [link](https://repl.it/languages/c) and the code is perfectly executed up to `LEN=1000000`, however when I have chosen `LEN=4000000` I have obtained a segmentation error. In addition this web IDE requires that main is int.

Comment: Moreover I know that malloc/calloc is the preferable way to allocate memory but I wanted to try a minimal program. In fact **now the program works** even with **a larger array** in **Atom**.

Comment: @Siderius: That probably just means that those other compilers/linkers have a higher default setting for the maximum stack size.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel As I wrote in a particle physics fashion a cutoff on memory. But are malloc related to the stack?

Comment: @Siderius: No, memory allocated with `malloc` is allocated on the so-called "heap", whereas non-`static` local variables are allocated on the "stack".